# How to "fill in" a 2d grid based on neighbors

Tags: matrix-equations, smooth-functions, sparse-matrices

I've got an array of elevations on a plane, but there are missing values.  Specifically it is elevations I derived from lunar satellite data regarding the south pole.  I'd like to use the data to make a 1m x 1m x 1m terrain map but need a nice way to "fill" in any missing data in my array.

ex.. [[500, ??, ??, 517],[??, ??, 512, 514]]

I'd like to estimate / fill in the missing values programmatically, in a way that is even and consistent (even if not exactly precise).

Here is an example of my current array, coded to a PNG, with white level based on relative y value:

[image: Lunar South Pole 89'S]

I'm unaware of, but certain there is a relatively straight forward mathematic mutation that completes my matrix, but I'm totally unaware of the right things to search for.  Bonus points if the solution is in Javascript, but a conversion is something I can hack if needed. :)

Further challenging is that data itself is actually pretty sparse as the 1m resolution desired isn't anywhere close to the beams of data that was collected.  The top image was generated by compressing the known points by 1000.  The actual data has elevation for some points, but most points are unknown, here is an uncompressed 100m x 100m square from right on the south pole (unknown data is colored magenta, while the little grey pixels are known altitudes):

[image: Sparse Render]

Comment: What about linear estimation between known neighbours?

Comment: It sounds like a [noise removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_reduction) problem for image data and you noise looks like a [salt-and-peper noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt-and-pepper_noise). According to wiki, an effective algorithm for this type of noise is a [median filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) or [morphological filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology). look at above wiki entries for a start. [dsp.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) should have more experts for this.

Comment: I clarified a little bit in the description, the data is actually pretty sparse.  I was thinking that there should be a way to estimate a value for the unknown based on a weighted average of the closest known data points... but what this is called is not known to me.

Comment: @achillehui - While this may look like noise, it's actually fairly close to real altitude data, I'd like to leave any known points in tact, and just smooth to figure out the points where the values are unknown.

Comment: Okay, it will be a completely different problem. if your data are sparse but reasonably accurate, then it is a [spatial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation) problem over irregular gird (scattered data). Look at wiki entry for methods available. You should also use that as search key to see whether there are any library implementing those methods.

Comment: Thanks, @achillehui - I think a bicubic interpolation was exactly what I'm looking for (though wouldn't have stumbled on those terms without your help) -- Any chance you could help me with a more specific term for a bicubic interpolation for a non-uniformly spaced data set?  Most of the libraries and tools I'm stumbling across are for expanding a discrete, uniformly spaced set - https://www.npmjs.com/package/2d-bicubic-interpolate - which unfortunately is not representative of my data.